# MySQL query via multiple foreign keys

Tags: mysql, join

Basically, what i need to do is count, how many times each sponsor (from table Sponsors) participated in each Type_name (from Event_types). I imagine its done via multiple JOIN queries, but i seem to get lost very quickly.

Here is the picture of my database.

[Picture of SQL database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiXTK.png)

Thanks in advance.

P.S, ignore the database name, local server doesnt allow me to create more than  5 separate databases so had to use an existing one for my side project :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.Club, e.Event_Type, count(sr.Sponsor) as totalsponsoring
from Sponsoring sr
join Sponsors s on s.Sponsor_name = sr.Sponsor
join Clubs c on c.Club = sr.Club
join Events e on e.Club = c.Club
group by sr.Sponsor
```

Comment: thats not what im looking for, unfortunately. look asnwer below, i will provide you with what i've achieved so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    events.event_type,
    sponsoring.sponsor,
    count(sponsing.id) 
from sponsoring 
join events on sponsoring.club = events.club
group by 
    events.event_type, 
    sponsoring.sponsor
```

If you need the clubs table:

```
select 
    events.event_type,
    sponsoring.sponsor,
    count(sponsing.id) 
from sponsoring 
join clubs on sponsoring.club = clubs.club
join events on clubs.club = events.club
group by 
    events.event_type, 
    sponsoring.sponsor
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do 2 separate queries to "connect" Event_types with Clubs and Clubs with sponsors. How do i make them into one?

```
SELECT Sponsors.Sponsor_name as Sponsor, Clubs.Club as Club FROM Sponsoring JOIN Sponsors ON Sponsoring.Sponsor=Sponsor_name JOIN Clubs ON Sponsoring.Club=Clubs.Club;
SELECT Clubs.Club as Club, Event_types.Type_name as Typename FROM Events JOIN Clubs on Events.Club=Clubs.Club JOIN Event_types ON Events.Event_type=Event_types.Type_name;
```

Comment: You should consider editing  your question than posting another question under  `answer`